# drupal 7 image field doesn't check image type

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules, image-uploading

if you rename **(file.php)** to **(file.jpg)** and you want to upload it

drupal 6 image_field module can detect it and refuse uploading this file
but image_field in drupal 7 can't detect it .

can you help me to find another module in drupal 7 can detect (REAL File type).

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the Drupal 7 doesnt have mime-type validation

someone did patch it in this link :
http://drupal.org/node/959800

Answer (score 0):

A website security audit company raised the same issue for one of my Drupal project. My scenario, if I changed .exe file to .jpg then try to upload via form, it was uploaded for me.

I searched on web and drupal community but didn't get any suitable answer.  Fianlly 
i edited in core  "include/file.inc" file and define supported mime type is "'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'".

But it is not recommended to change in Drupal core file. Here is the complete code :

Change in function file_validate_mime_type in "include/file.inc" file

```
 $errors = array();
 $allowedmimetype = explode('::', $mime_types);
 $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 $tmpmime =$finfo->file($file->uri);
 if (!in_array($tmpmime, $allowedmimetype) )
 {
    $errors[] = t('Not allowed this mime type '.$tmpmime.'! Only files with the  following mime type are allowed: %files-allowed.', array('%files-allowed' => $mime_types));
 }
 return $errors;
}
```

Added following 2 lines in file "modules/image/image_field.inc"

```
    $elements[$delta]['#upload_validators']['file_validate_mime_type'][0] = implode('::', $supported_mime);
```

before the following line

`$elements[$delta]['#process'][] = 'image_field_widget_process';`

The web security audit team passed this code. May be in future we will get some better answer.